# I'm trying to implement an Observer Pattern on C#, want to know did I do it right way?

Tags: observers

I'm very new on Observer Pattern, thought it very helpful in some cases, so I wrote a simple project, I'm not sure that I did it a right way or not, any suggestions will be appreciated.

```
class Program
    {
        public delegate void ProductAddedEventHandler(Object sender, ProductAddedEventArgs e);

        public class Products
        {
            private double subtotal;
            public event ProductAddedEventHandler ProductAdded;

            public void Add(Product product)
            {
                ProductModels model = new ProductModels();
                IEnumerable<Product> products = model.Products();
                IEnumerable<Product> new_Collection = products.Concat(new List<Product>() { product });

                Calculate calculate = new Calculate();
                this.subtotal = calculate.create(new_Collection);

                if (ProductAdded != null)
                {
                    ProductAddedEventArgs e = new ProductAddedEventArgs(subtotal);
                    ProductAdded(this, e);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Subtotal Amount: {0}", subtotal);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Calculate the Subtotal
        /// </summary>
        public class Calculate
        {
            public double create(IEnumerable<Product> products)
            {
                double result = 0;
                foreach (Product p in products)
                {
                    result += p.Price;
                }

                return result;
            }
        }

        public class ProductAddedEventArgs : EventArgs
        {
            public readonly double SubTotal;
            public ProductAddedEventArgs(double subtotal) => SubTotal = subtotal;
        }

        public class Shipping
        {
            const double Shipping_Rate = 0.05;

            public void create(Object sender, ProductAddedEventArgs e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Shipping Amount: {0}", e.SubTotal * Shipping_Rate);
            }
        }

        public class Discount
        {
            const double Discount_Rate = 0.2;
            public void create(Object sender, ProductAddedEventArgs e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Discount Amount: {0}", e.SubTotal * Discount_Rate);
            }
        }

        public class Tax
        {
            const double Tax_Rate = 0.07;

            public void create(Object sender, ProductAddedEventArgs e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Tax Amount: {0}", e.SubTotal * Tax_Rate);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Products products = new Products();
            Shipping shipping = new Shipping();
            Discount discount = new Discount();
            Tax tax = new Tax();

            products.ProductAdded += shipping.create;
            products.ProductAdded += discount.create;
            products.ProductAdded += tax.create;

            products.Add(new Product()
            {
                Id = 50,
                Name = "Watermelon",
                Price = 9.21
            });

        }
    }
```

BTW, How to get the total amount?

Comment: The "observers" (event handlers) need need to compute their value and return it somehow.. ie. maybe there is a TotalPrice column on the event object that is initially populated and then *updated*? However, this feels like a "not good" use of events/observers.. in particular, it is relatively hard to track such side-effects and ordering. Consider a trivial transformation sequence instead. Since this transformation is 1) computationally cheap and 2) may depend on content as a whole, simply re-apply it each time to the current product purchase/cart.. this can still utilize different functions.

Comment: @user2864740, Thanks for your opinion and I agree with you that this is not a good sample for describing the Observer Pattern. but the pattern I've written above, it is  Observer Pattern, am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Although this question belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ but i'll try to write a brief answer.

The definition of Observer pattern from DoFactory(GOF),

> Observer pattern defines a one-to-many dependency between objects so that when one object changes state, all its dependents are notified and updated automatically.

In your example you have't defined any observer instead you have events that are changing the state of the object itself. And there are too many responsibility or work being done in Add() method.

The example of the Observer could be a shopping cart(e-commerce) e.g. When the products count is changed then the order summary object should know about it and re-calculate the summary(taxes, discount, total etc.). See below example for a Cart and Order Summary being updated as Observer of cart items. It is not perfect but it will give you a notion of Observer pattern:

```
class Product
{
    // Product properties
}

class ProductCollection
{
    private List<Observer> _observers = new List<Observer>();
    List<Product> _internalcol = new List<Product>();

    public void Attach(Observer observer)
    {
      _observers.Add(observer);
    }

    public void Detach(Observer observer)
    {
      _observers.Remove(observer);
    }

    public void Add(Product p)
    {
        _internalcol.Add(p)
        Notify();
    }

    public void Remove(Product p)
    {

    }

    private void Notify()
    {
      foreach (Observer o in _observers)
      {
        o.Update();
      }
    }
}

class Cart
{
    public ProductionCollection products = new ProductionCollection();
    public OrderSummary summary = new OrderSummary();

    public Cart()
    {
        products.Attach(new OrderSummary(products));
    }

    public void AddProduct(Product p, int count)
    {
        if(count > 1){
            foreach(int i in count){
                products.Add(p);
            }
        else if(count == 1){
            products.Add(p);
        }
        else if(count == 0)
        {
            products.Remove(p);
        }
    }
}

abstract class Observer()
{
    abstract void Update();
}

class OrderSummary: Observer
{
    ProductionCollection _products;

     // Constructor
    public OrderSummary(ProductionCollection products)
    {
        this._products = products;
    }

    public override void Update()
    {
      //Recalculate taxes, discount etc. here.
      // Update Summary object
    }

    public void GetSummary()
    {
        // return/print Summary object;
    }
}

class program
{
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Cart c = new Cart();
            c.products.AddProduct(
                new Product()
                {
                    Id = 50,
                    Name = "Watermelon",
                    Price = 9.21
                });
        }
}
```

It may not compile I wrote it in Notepad.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!


About "In your example you have't defined any observer instead you have events that are changing the state of the object itself", by my understanding, I thought the classes 'Shipping,Discount,Tax' are all Observers, cause they all interesting with 'Subtotal' in class 'Product'

Comment: Observer shouldn’t change object state rather they rely on it.

Comment: I'm confused right now,  as you can see,  those classes 'Shipping, Discount, Tax', they don't change class Product's state, Instead, they got changed by it, am I right?